# AWS storage service for multi-tenant web app

Tags: amazon-web-services, multi-tenant

Which services are handy for creating a specific amount of storage allocation for each tenant, increasing/decreasing capacity, and monitoring free and used capacity.

Answer (score 2):

The most flexible storage option on Amazon Web Services is S3 - Simple Storage Service.

S3 is an object store storage facility with which you can upload objects of any type. S3 also support multipart uploads for big files.

To separate your different tenants data, you could use folders in a bucket and do some application logic to stop different tenants accessing each others files.

You can use bucket policies to give different IAM users access to different folders, however, it wouldn't make sense to create an IAM user for each of your tenants.

I encourage you to read the docs:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Welcome.html

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I'll be going for S3. What is the advantage of assigning each tenant a folder vs bucket?

Comment: There is a limit of 100 buckets. You can submit a bucket limit increase but for this kind of use case it's probably not going to be approved. It would be better to give each tenant a folder.